# How to get the OneSignal Push Notfications when the app is closed?

Tags: android, push-notification, onesignal

I have implemented the Onesignal Push notification in my App,but i am not getting the push notification when my app is closed.Here is my code for the Implementation.

**LoginActivity.java**

```
public class LoginActivity extends BaseActivity {

    private static final int REQUEST_MARK_READ = 165;
    private ListView userListView;
    private static final String TAG = LoginActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private static ArrayList<String> userids=new ArrayList<>();
    private static boolean activityStarted;

    public static void start(Context context) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, LoginActivity.class);
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (activityStarted && getIntent() != null && (getIntent().getFlags() & Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT) != 0)
        {
            finish();
            return;
        }
        activityStarted = true;
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        if (SharedPreferencesUtil.hasQbUser()) {
            try {
                Onesignal();
                recreateChatSession();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return;
        }
        Onesignal();

        userListView = _findViewById(R.id.list_login_users);
        TextView listHeader = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(this)
                .inflate(R.layout.include_list_hint_header, userListView, false);
        listHeader.setText(R.string.login_select_user_for_login);

        userListView.addHeaderView(listHeader, null, false);
        userListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnUserLoginItemClickListener());
        buildUsersList();
    }


    public void Onesignal()
    {
          /*5 oct 2016*/
        OneSignal.idsAvailable(new OneSignal.IdsAvailableHandler() {
            @Override
            public void idsAvailable(String userId, String registrationId) {
                registrationId= NotificationUtilities.getRegistrationId(getApplicationContext());

                userids.add(userId);
                String text = "OneSignal UserID:\n" + userId + "\n\n";

//                try {
//                    OneSignal.postNotification(new JSONObject("{'contents': {'en':'"+ PrivateChatImpl.chat_message +"'}, 'include_player_ids': ['" + userId + "']}"), null);
//                } catch (JSONException e) {
//                    e.printStackTrace();
//                }

                try {
                    OneSignal.postNotification(new JSONObject("{'contents': {'en':'" + PrivateChatImpl.chat_message.size() + "','en':'Unread Messages'}, 'include_player_ids': ['" + userId + "']}"),
                            new OneSignal.PostNotificationResponseHandler() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(JSONObject response) {

                                    Log.i("OneSignalExample", "postNotification Success: " + JsonResponse());
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onFailure(JSONObject response) {
                                    Log.e("OneSignalExample", "postNotification Failure: " + JsonResponse());
                                }
                            });
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                if (registrationId != null)
                    text += "Google Registration Id:\n" + registrationId;
                else
                    text += "Google Registration Id:\nCould not subscribe for push";

            }
        });


         /*5 oct 2016*/
    }

    public String JsonResponse()
    {
        String jsonResponse = null;
        try {

            URL url = new URL("https://onesignal.com/api/v1/notifications");
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            con.setUseCaches(false);
            con.setDoOutput(true);
            con.setDoInput(true);

            con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
            con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic NGEwMGZmMjItY2NkNy0xMWUzLTk5ZDUtMDAwYzI5NDBlNjJj");
            con.setRequestMethod("POST");

            String strJsonBody = "{"
                    +   "\"app_id\": \"05b29c2d-ea2a-487f-88e8-63438bd58831\","
                    +   "\"include_player_ids\": "+userids+","
                    +   "\"data\": {\"foo\": \"bar\"},"
                    +   "\"contents\": {\"en\": \"English Message\"}"
                    + "}";


            System.out.println("strJsonBody:\n" + strJsonBody);

            byte[] sendBytes = strJsonBody.getBytes("UTF-8");
            con.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(sendBytes.length);

            OutputStream outputStream = con.getOutputStream();
            outputStream.write(sendBytes);

            int httpResponse = con.getResponseCode();
            System.out.println("httpResponse: " + httpResponse);

            if (  httpResponse >= HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK
                    && httpResponse < HttpURLConnection.HTTP_BAD_REQUEST) {
                Scanner scanner = new Scanner(con.getInputStream(), "UTF-8");
                jsonResponse = scanner.useDelimiter("\\A").hasNext() ? scanner.next() : "";
                scanner.close();
            }
            else {
                Scanner scanner = new Scanner(con.getErrorStream(), "UTF-8");
                jsonResponse = scanner.useDelimiter("\\A").hasNext() ? scanner.next() : "";
                scanner.close();
            }
            System.out.println("jsonResponse:\n" + jsonResponse);

        } catch(Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }

        return jsonResponse;
    }
```

**MyShopApplication.java**

```
public class MyShopApplication extends Application {
    private Tracker mTracker;
        private static MyShopApplication INSTANCE;

        final GooglePlayServicesHelper googlePlayServicesHelper = new GooglePlayServicesHelper();
        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        INSTANCE=this;
        HttpService.getInstance().setUp(getApplicationContext());
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
            sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(AppConstants.USER_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

//            OneSignal.startInit(this).init();
//        OneSignal.enableNotificationsWhenActive(true);
//        OneSignal.setLogLevel(OneSignal.LOG_LEVEL.DEBUG, OneSignal.LOG_LEVEL.DEBUG);

            /* 5 october 2016 */

//            OneSignal.setLogLevel(OneSignal.LOG_LEVEL.DEBUG, OneSignal.LOG_LEVEL.WARN);
            OneSignal.startInit(this)
                    .setNotificationOpenedHandler(new ExampleNotificationOpenedHandler())
                    .setNotificationReceivedHandler(new ExampleNotificationReceivedHandler())
                    .autoPromptLocation(true)
                    .inFocusDisplaying(OneSignal.OSInFocusDisplayOption.None)
                    .disableGmsMissingPrompt(true)
                    .init();

            /*11 oct 2016*/
            OneSignal.clearOneSignalNotifications();
            OneSignal.syncHashedEmail(sharedPreferences.getString(AppConstants.USER_EMAIL, ""));
            /*11 oct 2016*/


            /*Registering for push notifications happens automatically on Android using OneSignal.
             You don't need to write anything!*/

            /* 5 oct 2016*/


        Crashlytics crashlyticsKit = new Crashlytics.Builder()
                .core(new CrashlyticsCore.Builder()/*.disabled(BuildConfig.DEBUG)*/.build())
                .build();

        Fabric.with(this, crashlyticsKit, new Crashlytics(), new Crashlytics());

        GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
        analytics.setLocalDispatchPeriod(15);//setting dispatching to 15mins, Default is 30 mins
        // To enable debug logging use: adb shell setprop log.tag.GAv4 DEBUG
        mTracker = analytics.newTracker(R.xml.global_tracker);
        mTracker.enableAutoActivityTracking(true);


    }




    /* 5 october 2016 */

    private class ExampleNotificationOpenedHandler implements OneSignal.NotificationOpenedHandler {
        // This fires when a notification is opened by tapping on it.
        @Override
        public void notificationOpened(OSNotificationOpenResult result) {
            OSNotificationAction.ActionType actionType = result.action.type;
            JSONObject data = result.notification.payload.additionalData;
            String customKey;

            if (data != null) {
                customKey = data.optString("customkey", null);
                if (customKey != null)
                    Log.i("OneSignalExample", "customkey set with value: " + customKey);
            }

            if (actionType == OSNotificationAction.ActionType.ActionTaken)
                Log.i("OneSignalExample", "Button pressed with id: " + result.action.actionID);

            // The following can be used to open an Activity of your choice.

             Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                     com.baniaclothing.rang.quickblox.ui.activity.LoginActivity.class);
             intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
             startActivity(intent);

            // Add the following to your AndroidManifest.xml to prevent the launching of your main Activity
            //  if you are calling startActivity above.
         /*
            <application ...>
              <meta-data android:name="com.onesignal.NotificationOpened.DEFAULT" android:value="DISABLE" />
            </application>
         */
        }
    }
    /* 5 october 2016 */

    /* 5 october 2016 */
    private class ExampleNotificationReceivedHandler implements OneSignal.NotificationReceivedHandler {
        @Override
        public void notificationReceived(OSNotification notification) {
            JSONObject data = notification.payload.additionalData;
            String customKey;

            if (data != null) {
                customKey = data.optString("customkey", null);
                if (customKey != null)
                    Log.i("OneSignalExample", "customkey set with value: " + customKey);
            }
        }
    }

    /* 5 october 2016 */
}
```

When i tap on the notification then my LoginActivity.java is launched ,and when i open my app then notification are being shown,but when i close my app then no notification is being shown.

**Manifest_file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.baniaclothing.rang" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <!-- Keeps the processor from sleeping when a message is received. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />


    <!-- Creates a custom permission so only this app can receive its messages. -->
    <permission
        android:name="com.baniaclothing.rang.quickblox.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.baniaclothing.rang.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <!-- This app has permission to register and receive data message. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <application
        android:name=".MyShopApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/app_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.onesignal.BadgeCount"
            android:value="DISABLE" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.onesignal.NotificationOpened.DEFAULT"
            android:value="DISABLE" />

        <activity
            android:name=".quickblox.ui.activity.LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/login_title"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" />

        <service
            android:name=".NotificationExtenderExample"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.onesignal.NotificationExtender" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />


    </application>

</manifest>
```

**NotificationExtenderExample**

```
public class NotificationExtenderExample extends NotificationExtenderService {

    final static String GROUP_KEY_EMAILS = "group_key_emails";


    @Override
    protected boolean onNotificationProcessing(OSNotificationReceivedResult receivedResult) {
        OverrideSettings overrideSettings = new OverrideSettings();
        overrideSettings.extender = new NotificationCompat.Extender() {
            @Override
            public NotificationCompat.Builder extend(NotificationCompat.Builder builder) {
                // Sets the background notification color to Green on Android 5.0+ devices.
                return builder.setColor(new BigInteger("FF00FF00", 16).intValue())
                              .setGroup(GROUP_KEY_EMAILS)
                              .setGroupSummary(true);
            }
        };

        OSNotificationDisplayedResult displayedResult = displayNotification(overrideSettings);
        Log.d("OneSignalExample", "Notification displayed with id: " + displayedResult.androidNotificationId);

        return true;
    }
}
```

**Logcat**

```
  10-14 08:56:55.683 4581-4581/com.baniaclothing.rang I/REgistraationId:: dKV-blhGGI4:APA91bFpbOMERKf_IlZ3JI9P2ngOY5EXFF7kaUyuuHSL1SGsi5qLPDGDoyJPKyA1OvK5Jd_4TfHjWQJjO-SqQY5g7tTY2ThGOusbBJwH-8-IDhxsqYeUJzvfQtJl8cvW9qOhsnTnswp7
10-14 08:56:56.287 4581-6086/com.baniaclothing.rang I/System.out: strJsonBody:
10-14 08:56:56.287 4581-6086/com.baniaclothing.rang I/System.out: {"app_id": "000000000-0000-0000-0000-0000000000","include_player_ids": [ecbef570-f713-4fb0-ada2-e7b9b864344b],"data": {"foo": "bar"},"contents": {"en": "English Message"}}
10-14 08:56:56.686 4581-6086/com.baniaclothing.rang I/System.out: httpResponse: 400
10-14 08:56:56.692 4581-6086/com.baniaclothing.rang I/System.out: jsonResponse:
10-14 08:56:56.692 4581-6086/com.baniaclothing.rang I/System.out: {"status":400,"error":"There was a problem in the JSON you submitted: unexpected character at line 1, column 74 [parse.c:652]"}
10-14 08:56:56.692 4581-6086/com.baniaclothing.rang I/OneSignalExample: postNotification Success: {"status":400,"error":"There was a problem in the JSON you submitted: unexpected character at line 1, column 74 [parse.c:652]"}
```

**Note**-Please ignore the unnecessary method calls in the java files.I have just shown the code related to the OneSignal Push Notification.
**Why am i not getting the notification when my app is closed ?**

Answer (score 2):

If you are closing your app by putting it into a "Force Stopped" state most events including GCM/FCM messages for push notifications will not be received. An app can be placed in this state in the following ways.

- From Settings > Apps, "Force Stop" is pressed.
- Long pressing the back button on some devices.
- Using a 3rd party task killer like Greenify.
- App is closed on some Huawei, Xiaomi, or Sony devices due their custom Android tweaks. The following device settings can be changed to prevent this.

  - Huawei - Go to Settings > "Protected apps", check your app.
  - Xiaomi  - Make sure "Auto-start" property enabled for your app in the settings.
  - Sony - Tap on the battery icon. Go to Power Management > STAMINA mode > Apps active in standby > Add your app.

To confirm your app state is the issue send a few notifications and check for the following GCM logcat entry.

```
W/GCM-DMM: broadcast intent callback: result=CANCELLED forIntent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE pkg=com.onesignal.example (has extras) }
```

Some device manufactures will white list apps from going into the force closed state. Example such as Gmail and Whatsapp.

See [OneSignal's documentation](https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/notifications-show-successful-but-are-not-being-shown) on this for more details.

Comment: I have checked this issue,but this is not the problem ,My settings of the phone are absolutely correct .

Comment: Can check your logcat for the `GCM` entry above when you send a notification? Can you test your app another Android device? Add the OS version and model number of devices you have tested and how you are closing the app.

Comment: there is no entry being shown in the logcat regarding GCM

Comment: I didnt included any code for registration of GCM.And my logcat is also not showing anything regarding GCM

Comment: I have updated my Logcat in the question ,just have a look at it .

Comment: The resulting the logcat show you tried to schedule a notification but there was a syntax error. `+   "\"include_player_ids\": "+userids+","` should be `+   "\"include_player_ids\": \""+userids+"\","`.

Comment: It is showing in the Logcat that `include_player_ids must be an array`??
I have stored the Player_ids in an array named "userid" ,now how to pass that array in the strJsonBody..??

Comment: @jkasten Hello, I have the same problem: "ActivityManager: Unable to start service Intent { act=com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT pkg=com.nextwebart.senego launchParam=MultiScreenLaunchParams { mDisplayId=0 mFlags=0 } (has extras) } U=0: not found"

So there is no solution for that?

Comment: @DennyWeinberg The error you listed is not being able to start a service. The BroadcastReceiver would have already fired so you aren't running into the force close issue in this case. It seems like an issue with how the FCM library is setup in your app.

Comment: @jkasten Oh, that is interesting! Thanks. I will double check all the code. But I followed the tutorials. Sometimes it works, sometimes not.

Comment: @DennyWeinberg You don't need to add the FCM library with OneSignal, it is recommend not to include it as it can create conflicts. If you are still running into an issue you can open an issue on GitHub and provide more details. https://github.com/onesignal